# Access Report not showing zeroes on Currency fields

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm in Access 2007 and I have a few fields that are currency fields.  I have a report that shows these fields.  When the value is something like $180.00, it only shows $180 on the report.  If the value is something like $180.80, it only show $180.8 on the report.  Basically, no zeroes after the decimal are shown.

Everything I try as far as setting the Format or the decimal parameters doesn't fix this. I wrote this to try to add in the zeroes on .00 values

```
="   $" & [Amount] & IIf([Amount] Like '*.*',"",".00")
```

But this doesn't work for when I only need one zero ($180.8).

Does anyone know how I can get this to just display an amount like you would normally see it?  Or  if not, is there a way to get around this to account for when I need one zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an expression to display your *[Amount]* values as currency, you can base that expression on the `Format()` function:

```vb
Amount = 180
? Format(Amount, "Currency")
$180.00
```

However I don't understand why that should be necessary.  I offered that suggestion only as an alternative to your expression which doesn't give you the desired result.

I have a table with a field whose Data Type is Currency and Auto for its Decimal Places property.  In Datasheet View, those values are always displayed with 2 decimal places.

And I have a report with a text box with that same field as its Control Source.  The text box Format property is blank, and its Decimal Places property is Auto.  That report displays those Currency values with 2 decimal places.

I described what I see in Access 2010.  As best I recall, that is the same thing I saw with this report in Access 2007.  So I can only suggest you compare my description to what you have and see if any of your details are different.

Comment: I did exactly what you said and it worked, which allowed me to figure out what was making it not work.  I didn't have a textbox with just [Amount] as control property, I had it doing `="  $" & [Amount]` because I couldn't get the formatting right.  Doing it this way leads it to omit the zeroes.  I will change my report BUT if I needed to do a text box that is something like `="I have " & [Amount] & " dollars."`, for example, is there a way I could get it to do the zeroes, or am I out of luck?

Comment: `"I have " & Format([Amount], "Currency") & " dollars."`

Comment: of course, I should have known.  once again I learn from you, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to design view of the table where the values are stored.
Set the value to currency, and use the decimal property at the bottom to set it to 2 decimal places. This should propagate throughout your reports and forms.

Also change your Property from Long Integer to Double.

[image: Capture Decimal Places]

or

[image: Capture 2]

Comment: thanks, i have done that but it still doesn't work on the report.  they display correctly in the tables and queries.

Comment: oh I see, sorry.  That works in that it displays the zeroes, but it is changing the values.  I can't have it do that.

Comment: it's rounding, it turned 588.95 into 589.00

Comment: Seems to me the data type should be Currency.  I thought that's what msim told us he's using in the question.

Comment: My bad, that may be misleading. You can use Currency + 2 decimal places or Number -> Double -> 2 Decimals